# REST API DESIGN: POST OR GET when a URL is the query parameter

Tags: api, rest, post, get, api-design

I am writing an API and it will support a query where a URL will be the query term, eg: return the id of a document that has the data `{"url":"http://google.com/directory/directory/document/index.html"}`

the API url would be something like this `/document/getid`

From my reading GET should be used to do queries but when the query could be  very long URL, is that still the best option, I am considering using POST but I want to follow API design best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do an md5 hash of the URL and store it as a field in the document